# A question regarding calculus in several variables.

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Let $f:\Bbb{R^n}\to \Bbb{R}$ be a continuous function. I refer to [this](http://poncelet.math.nthu.edu.tw/disk3/cal01/chain.pdf) proof of the Mean Value Theorem for several variables.

Here $g(t)=f(a+t(b-a))$.

Hence $g(t+h)-g(t)=f(a_1+t(b_1-a_1)+h(b_1-a_1),a_2+t(b_2-a_2)+h(b_2-a_2),\dots,a_n+t(b_n-a_n)+h(b_n-a_n))-f(a_1+t(b_1-a_1),a_2+t(b_2-a_2),\dots,a_n+t(b_n-a_n))$

Obviously $(a_1,a_2,\dots,a_n),(b_1,b_2,\dots,b_n)\in\Bbb{R^n}$.

Assuming that $f$ is differentiable at every point $(1-p)a+pb$
 for $p\in[0,1]$, we get $g(t+h)-g(t)=\nabla f(a+t(b-a)).h(b-a)$

> My question is: what is $\nabla f(a+t(b-a))$?? What variables are we differentiating $f$ with respect to? Are those variables $a_i+t(b_i-a_i)$??

Comment: It simply means the usual gradient, evaluated at that point. We take the vector of partials of $f$ with respect to $x_1,x_2,$ etc., then plug in the point $a+t(b-a)$.

Comment: @StrangerLoop- Got it. Thanks! Some really messed up stuff I was stuck in.